# Ionic 2 unable to update form value from class

Tags: typescript, ionic2

Im stuck while trying to update a form field using ionic 2, this is the spec:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.11
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.37
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.20
Node Version: v4.4.7
```

and this is the code so far:

```
      <form [formGroup]="blueForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <ion-item [class.error]="!deviceName.valid && deviceName.touched">
                <ion-label floating>Device Name</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="text" value="" formControlName="deviceName"></ion-input>         
            </ion-item>
            <div *ngIf="deviceName.hasError('required') && deviceName.touched"
                class="error-box">* Device Name is required!</div>               
            <br/><br/> 
            <ion-grid>
                <button type="submit" class="custom-button" [disabled]="!blueForm.valid" block>Change Name</button>
            </ion-grid>
        </form>
```

im trying to update the value using this function:

```
(<Control>this.blueForm.controls['deviceName']).updateValue('THE NEW VALUE', { onlySelf: true });
```

and here the form definition:

```
    blueForm: FormGroup;

    deviceName = new FormControl("", Validators.required);

    constructor(private platform: Platform, public navCtrl: NavController, private fb: FormBuilder, private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
        this.blueForm = fb.group({
            "deviceName": this.deviceName,
        });
    }
```

and finally the error is:

> Error TS2352: Neither type 'AbstractControl' nor type 'Control' is
>   assignable to the other.   Property 'updateValue' is missing in type
>   'AbstractControl'.

Answer (score 1):

You can update individual form field values using the following.

this.blueForm.controls['**name**'].**patchValue**('**new value**');
this.blueForm.controls['**name**'].**setValue**('**new value**');

For a detailed explanation, check this link https://toddmotto.com/angular-2-form-controls-patch-value-set-value

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is because the control is named `deviceName` but you're trying to set its value by doing `(<Control>this.blueForm.controls['name'])` (notice that deviceName != name)

Also, try using the `updateValueAndValidity(newValue)` instead of the `updateValue` method.

Comment: sorry that was just a typo error, i ll try the updateValueAndValidity soon, thanks

Comment: Sounds great. Please let me know if the issue is fixed or there's maybe something else :)

Comment: i ve fixed the issue by casting the control object to <formControl> instead of <control>

Comment: Glad to hear that! If you don't mind, please update the OP with that information so other SO users with the same issue could find the answer easier.